# from where should i learn about functionality of maven package

Tags: maven-3

I am working on a project which works through maven package
Is there any documentation available for maven package linux so that i can learn it in best way ..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven 2.0 is based around the central concept of a build lifecycle. What this means is that the process for building and distributing a particular artifact (project) is clearly defined.<sup>Apache</sup>

Start by looking at the [Apache Maven Project](http://maven.apache.org/guides/).  I think it will be a good start.